# Access MySQL view in JPA with Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, view

I have a spring boot app that connects to a MySQL DB and I have been able to work with the tables, but now I created a model, repository and service to access a view. I created one route in a controller to work with this view and I get the following error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist
```

In MySQL workbench when I look at the view it looks like this:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `db`.`my_view` AS
    ...
```

In application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${HOSTNAME:localhost}:${PORT:3306}/${DB_NAME:db}?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=${USERNAME:root}
spring.datasource.password=${PASSWORD:password}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
```

Do I need to change the definer in the DB? I am logged in as the same user as when I created it. Pls let me know if I need to add any information and any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix your error is removing any DEFINER statements from SQL script.

Comment: ok thanks! I tried removing it (removing the definer completely) but when I click on edit for the view the definer is there again just this time the host is not % but localhost. Now it works with my spring boot app locally but for example if I want to deploy this to AWS or so would that still work?

Comment: @AlfieDanger The DEFINER (and SQL SECURITY) clauses specify the security context to be used when checking access privileges at routine execution time.